# Using regex to find single quoted strings and what is in between them

Tags: c#, sql, regex, parsing

Currently I'm writing a really simple textbox-to-query parser for SQL queries. One of the things that needs to be done is strings that are placed in single quotes need to be found and properly parameterized. I've Googled it and look page after page for answers, however nothing I can find will help.

Given the query

```
INSERT INTO PracticeTable
VALUES ('Hello 'World')
```

or for example,

```
WHERE users.UserProfiles = 'John's Profile'
```

I need to figure out a way to

1. Find the string in single quotes
2. Extract the string from the inside

I can use a loop to do the parameterization myself.

So to complete the example in the query segment

```
WHERE users.UserProfiles = 'John's Profile'
```

I should get a match for 'John's Profile' and then be able to remove the entire string John's Profile from the inside of them.

Can anyone help me? Also, can anyone suggest a better way to receive a query from the user and run it? I'm always looking for suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the following. It will catch the quoted string.

```
[^']*'(.+)'
```

=>

> WHERE users.UserProfiles = 'John's Profile'

extracted group

> John's Profile

I want to mention that your WHERE clause is wrong SQL as your inside ' is not escaped.

---

As you asked, the quoted string can be captured fairly easy by:

```
[^']*('.+')
```

Comment: That's partially why I want to catch and properly parameterize the string. If I catch it and set it as a parameter it shouldn't matter. The big concern however was that if someone ran a query with single quotes it would spit out a syntax error even though the syntax was correct. It seems to be a common problem with C# and SQL.

Comment: Also, your regex works great. Now how would I catch the entire string including single quotes (e.g. 'John's Profile' exactly). Thank you!

Comment: I added to the answer how to capture it with quotes.